# Iterate through parent-child relation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json object

```
var data = [
  { 
    id:'D1'
    parent: "",
    name: 'D1'
  },{
    id:'Z1',
    parent: "D1",
    name: 'Z1'
  },{   
    id: 'T1',
    parent: "Z1",
    name: 'T1'
  },{   
    id: 'T2',
    parent: "Z1",
    name: 'T2'
  },{   
    id: 'C1',
    parent: "T2",
    name: 'C1'
  },{   
    id: 'Z2',
    parent: "D1",
    name: 'Z2'
  },{    
    id:'D2',
    parent: "",
    name: 'D2'
  },{   
    id:'Z3',
    parent: "D2",
    name: 'Z3'
  },{   
    id: 'T3',
    parent: "Z3",
    name: 'T3'
  },{   
    id: 'T4',
    parent: "Z3",
    name: 'T4'
  },{
    id: 'C2',
    parent: "T3",
    name: 'C2'
  } 
  .
  .
  .
];
```

and I want below output using Jquery

```
D1-Z1-T1,
D1-Z1-T2-C1,
D1-Z2,
D2-Z3-T3,
D2-Z3-T3-C2
.
.
.
```

I need help for achieving the result.

Comment: Please also share what you have tried so far.

Comment: What's the pattern for the output?

Comment: `I have a Json object` no you have an array.  Json has nothing to do with it.